# Is runpy safe to use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, runpy

I am writing some code that will require data from downstream the package hierarchy. Consider the following project structure:

```
├── app/
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── lib.py
│   └── subpck/
│       └── module.py
```

And the following code:

```
# lib.py
some_instance = SomeClass()

# subpck.module
from ..lib import some_instance
some_instance.a = 'abc'

# main.py
from .lib import some_instance
print(some_instance.a)
```

The key point here is that `main.py` does not import `subpck.module`, so the latter's code is not run. However, I have successfully used `runpy` in `main.py` to run `subpck.module` and have gotten the desired results.

My question is this:

If I can somehow figure out how to encapsulate the use of `runpy` in `SomeClass`, is it safe to do?

I have been reading the `runpy` [docs](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/runpy.html), but am nervous if I am missing something. I also haven't heard if this is a big "no-no" for code that may be used in production.

Any help is appreciated.